# jQuery - Image animation (right to left)

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to animate an image from right to left, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r9kvehfx/) but the opposite way round:-

```
<span id="logo"></span>

#logo {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bd/Random_App_Logo.png);
  width: 0;
  height: 646px;
  display: block;
}

$('#logo').animate({ width:'100%' });
```

I've tried:-

```
#logo {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bd/Random_App_Logo.png);
  width: 1350px;
  height: 646px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 1350px;
}

$('#logo').animate({ marginLeft:'0px' });
```

But the image needs to stay in the same position. I would use an overlay but the background is a background image so this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `background-position: right center;` to align the `background-image` to the right instead of the left of the `div` and `float: right;`to set the `div` to the right. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r9kvehfx/1/)

You also can do it without javascript [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r9kvehfx/3/)

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed(or absolute); right: 0;` will give you the desired effect.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r9kvehfx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this with your current css except set the width in css to 0px;

```
 $('#logo').animate({marginLeft: '0px', width: '1350px'}, 2000);
```